# Use work laptop to develop a product on home system using VNC

Tags: intellectual-property

I am planning to develop a private software product. I'm going to develop and save all code and documentation on the home system but to reduce headache of switching back and forth from the work laptop to home system, I want to use VNC to login in home system from work laptop and develop it. Can the product be considered as intellectual property of my company if they find out?

Comment: yes, private product but not in work hours. After work hours/weekend

Comment: Why not just use your home system? What is the overriding headache you're willing to venture into grey areas or potential career limiting actions for?

Comment: Due to inconvenience. My home system is desktop. So If I want to work on the project while talking with family or sit in bed or go  somewhere else and work on it then I won't be able to do it.  So may be not developing whole proj but some part of it using work computer.

Comment: It may not be considered intellectual property but your company may take a dim view of using company property for non-company purposes.  How do you explain it if you spill a drink on the laptop during one of your weekend coding sessions?  If you want portability buy a cheap laptop and use VNC on that

Comment: I have voted to close; this is entirely dependent on your company’s policy and the law in your jurisdiction.

Comment: Don't take the risk. They could take automatic screenshots of your work laptop. Or they could find out through other ways. How much does a cheap laptop cost these days? Not much. Buy a used one if you don't have the money for a new one.

Answer (score 12):

Why even take the risk?

Work on it from your home computer when you're at home.

Don't work on it on your work computer, don't work on it on your work time, and don't connect to your home computer from your work computer for any reason.

Comment: This answer is good.  Bottom Line: Don't be a Richard Hendricks.

Answer (score 8):

It's trivial to argue in court that the work equipment assisted you in development of the product, otherwise, why would you be using it?

We have no idea of your jurisdiction so we can't speak to the legal aspect, but what I would say that using work equipment in my jurisdiction is enough to make the intellectual property the property of the employer.